# Potential effects of magnets on a Police Taser?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, voltage, electronics

I couldn't find any similar topics and was curious if anyone had thoughts on the following:

Could a magnet (ceramic and/or neodymium etc.) have an adverse affect on a Police Taser, if held to the Taser or held in proximity to the Taser.  If yes, is there a material that the magnet could be covered in, to insulate those effects?  (i.e. by effect, meaning unintentional discharge of the Taser, or causing the electronics on board to malfunction.)

Thanks for any color you may have on this, much appreciated.